# Setting state variable in react loop with conditional logic

Tags: reactjs

It appears that React does not like when you are setting the app state in a loop, so I was curious as to what the best approach for something like this was?

I have some logic that I am attempting to count the number of times the `input` variable is greater than the `stat` variable in my loop:

```
const [ statTotal, setStatTotal ] = useState(0);
{
    month.events.map((game) => {
        return (
            <tr key={ game.eventId }>
                <td>{ new Date(events[game.eventId].gameDate).toDateString() }</td>
                <td>{ events[game.eventId].atVs } { events[game.eventId].opponent.abbreviation }</td>
                <td>{ events[game.eventId].gameResult } { events[game.eventId].score }</td>
                {   
                    game.stats.map((stat, i) => {
                        
                        let className = '';

                        if (input > parseInt(stat)) {
                           className = 'red';
                           setStatTotal(statTotal + 1);
                        } else {
                           className = 'green';
                        }

                        return (
                            <td key={ i } className={ className }>{ stat }</td>
                        );
                    })

                }
            </tr>
        );
    }) 
}
```

Is there a better way to do the logic and share the variable within the app state?

**Edit** I have cleaned up my original syntax and added a little more information for some additional clarity. My data is a little construed as it's broken down by months, then into a single game date, then each stat array for that game.

My input is a selected stat area and I am trying to capture the total number of times that particular stat is above the inputted stat number.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is an amazing way to do that.

```
const totalStats = game.stats.filter(stat => stat < input).length;

return (
     <div>
    {
       game.stats.map((stat, i) => {
         if (stat < input ) {
             return <td key={ i } className={"red"}>{ stat }</td>;
         } else return <td key={ i } className={"green"}>{ stat }</td>;
    }
    </div>   
)
```

Answer (score 0):

`statTotal` looks to be a derived value, and it's not advised to use state for that.

Instead you can use just prepare some data for use in the render.

```
const totalStats = game.stats.filter(stat => input > stat).length
```

This filters the stats down to only the ones that pass your test and counts them. You can then use `totalStats` anywhere in your JSX to show that value.

If that list is very large and you want to improve performance, you could wrap that in a `useMemo` hook.

```
const totalStats =
  useMemo(() => game.stats.filter(stat => stat < input).length, [game.stats])
```

Now it will only recalculate the value when `game.stats` is changed.

---

Now when you render you can simplify this loop greatly since you don't have to do counting.

```
return <>
  {
    game.stats.map(stat => (
      <td key={i} className={input > stat ? 'red' : 'green'}>{ stat }</td>
    ))
  }
</>
```

Comment: I have added some additional context. My `game.stats` is mapped from an object, so I am unsure if I can easily use a `useMemo` or `filter` on the data object.